# De que manera puedo abrir un segundo activity Circle Menu View (libreria ramotion github)

Tags: java, android

estoy tratando de usar la liberia de ramotion, circle menu view, logra un menu muy bonito, soy nuevo en android y he aprendido a abrir actividades con boton pero con esto estoy liado. La pregunta es: cómo puedo llamar a mi segunda o 3er activity.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final CircleMenuView menu = findViewById(R.id.circle_menu);
        menu.setEventListener(new CircleMenuView.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMenuOpenAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuOpenAnimationStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuOpenAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuOpenAnimationEnd");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuCloseAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuCloseAnimationStart");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMenuCloseAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view) {
                Log.d("D", "onMenuCloseAnimationEnd");
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClickAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonClickAnimationStart| index: " + index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonClickAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonClickAnimationEnd| index: " + index);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onButtonLongClick(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonLongClick| index: " + index);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonLongClickAnimationStart(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonLongClickAnimationStart| index: " + index);
            }

            @Override
            public void onButtonLongClickAnimationEnd(@NonNull CircleMenuView view, int index) {
                Log.d("D", "onButtonLongClickAnimationEnd| index: " + index);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

La tarea que debería completar es que por cada elemento del menu abra una nueva actividad. He intentado varias cosas pero sin éxito. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Usa el Index de onButtonClickAnimationEnd(...) para identificar que Activity tenes que abrir, puedes usar un switch o muchos if else. Intentalo y si no te sale lo subes y te seguimos ayudando.

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir un MainActivity dandole a uno de las opciones del menú lo que debes crear otra clase activity la cual vas a llamar al pulsar la opcion del menú que quieras y llamarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this.Context);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

si esto no te sirve o no sabes como implementarlo seria de mayor utilidad que enviases el código de tu pantalla para saber que tipo de objeto es la opcion de menu, en caso de ser como un botón la accion a usar para implementar el codigo descrito antes es:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent (this.Context);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    }
```